# Change bookmark automatically

Tags: google-chrome

I love cyanide and happiness. So much so that I have it bookmarked and on my bookmarks toolbar. However, doing this isn't perfect as it brings me to the site but not directly to today's comic.

The URL of today's looks like this: 
http://www.explosm.net/comics/3173/

Yesterday it was http://www.explosm.net/comics/3172/

Is there any way that I can get my bookmark to change automatically so tomorrow it will be http://www.explosm.net/comics/3174/?

Comment: You can try to right-click on the image and open it in another tab. You should now be able to bookmark that tab, without it changing the address every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bookmark http://www.explosm.net/comics/new/ this url alway points to the latest comic

Answer (score 1):

This Chrome extension can update your existing bookmark so you can continue from where you left off:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/following-bookmarks/ikjggbacckafalikldfmcjndhgopeoan

Comment: Perfect!  Does just what I was looking for!